# I have Location but in terms of Google map URL and want to convert it into address

Tags: flutter, google-maps, location

I have Location but in terms of Google map URL and want to convert it into address.  Can anyone tell me How to Do it ? I am using Flutter and MongoDB as a DB . I am storing merchants Live Location in terms of Google Map Location (https...) and want it its address.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes the issue was solved

Comment: okay, may I know by which way you have solved this issue

Comment: I changed the schema of DB only instead of having live coordinates I stored the address because the merchant Address is going to be same everytime. Apart from that there is geocoder package which will convert Coordinates in to address, so yes.

Comment: okay @Khushi Sanghvi

Answer (score 1):

You can call a http request to google API

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse

If you don't have YOUR_API_KEY (google API key for maps) you can create it

Answer (score 1):

```
geocoding: ^2.1.0
```

> To translate an address into latitude and longitude coordinates you can use the `placemarkFromAddress` method

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

List<Location> locations = await locationFromAddress("Gronausestraat 710, Enschede");
```

> If you want to translate latitude and longitude coordinates into an
> address you can use the `placemarkFromCoordinates` method

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(52.2165157, 6.9437819);
```